# Swift 4 - using a variable to select dictionary

Tags: swift

I have a number of dictionarys in my swift code that have a standard naming convention. What I am trying to do is programmatically selection which dictionary to extract the data from. As as example

```
var listSelectionValue = "aaaa"

let aaaalist : [Int : String ] = [1: "first value in aaaaa", 2 : "second value in aaaa"]

let bbbblist : [Int : String ] =[1: "first value in bbbb", 2 : "second value in bbbb"]
```

I then want to use the value in `listSelectionValue` for pull data from the correct dictionary. Sorry if this is  exceedingly obvious, maybe I don't know right terminology to search for !!

Cheers,

Cameron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An if then else question?

```
 var listSelectionValue = "aaaa"
let aaaalist = [Int : String ]()

if listSelectionValue == "aaaa"{
aaaalist : [Int : String ] = [1: "first value in aaaaa", 2 : "second value in aaaa"]
}
else{
let bbbblist : [Int : String ] =[1: "first value in bbbb", 2 : "second value in bbbb"]
}
```

Comment: Damn - first question on the forum - a response in minutes. Awesome!!

Thanks Steve

Comment: If you have time, could you mark this as the answer? Thanks.